# Justified text layout in Android?

Tags: java, android

Is there any possibility to do a block of text in a justify layout?

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't support full justification.

you could try android:gravity="fill_horizontal", but from what I read it doesn't seem to work properly either.

As an alternate method you could use :

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
```

and

```
android:gravity="right"
```

The gravity attribute specifies how to align the text inside the TextView.
The layout_gravity specifies how to align the TextView element itself.

I'm sorry I couldn't be of further assistance.